# Please prove: $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}} = 0 $

Tags: limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$ \lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136626/lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-is-infinite)

Please prove:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}} = 0
$$

Comment: Have you tried using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirlings_approximation ?

Comment: "Please do my homework." Well, at least you were polite...

Comment: Please show what you have tried or tell us what is causing trouble. This helps to address whatever you don't understand.

Comment: Could someone who has upvoted this question explain why they did so?

Comment: @robjohn: Thank you for telling me this. I'll post more next time I ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$0<\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}}=\left(1\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdots\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{n}<\frac{1+\ln n}{n}$$

As $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+\ln n}{n}=0$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}}=0$

Comment: Squeeze theorem and aritmetic-mean-geometric-mean inequality used. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic-geometric_mean_inequality

Comment: @mick Also $$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}<\log n$$

Comment: Right Peter Tamaroff.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**: When writing out $n!$, you have 
\[ n! = n \cdot (n-1) \cdots \left\lceil \frac n2\right\rceil \cdots 1 \]
so at least $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ of the factors are larger then $\lceil \frac n2\rceil$.
So $n! \ge \lceil \frac n2\rceil^{\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor}$.

Answer (score -3):

Just try to put n equal to infinity. since 'n' appears in the denominator it will tend to zero.

Please confirm the answer.

Comment: (Downvoters, be nice.) Since you're new to the site, I suggest you take a look at other answers to see what people upvote. In the general case, it is better if you prove your claim, or at least sketch a proof. In this case, the problem is you get an indeterminate form $$\infty^0$$ Do you see why?

Comment: @fondoflior: No, you cannot deal with it like that. Because the degree is $\frac{1}{n}$ tend to zero too. If your method is feasible, how about $\sqrt[n]\frac{1}{n}$?