# How to prove $n!>(\frac{n}{e})^{n}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $n!>\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{n}$.

I used induction principle but cannot solve it for the $(m+1)$-th term after taking the $m$th term to be true.

Comment: Some of the answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338954/how-to-show-1-n1-n-goes-to-0-as-n-goes-to-infinity are related to this.

Answer (score 24):

Here the key is to use the appropriate definition of $e^x$, namely:

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}x^k$$

Plugging in $x = n$ we get

$$e^n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}n^k$$

and hence, breaking this sum up a little we get our inequality: $$n! e^n = n^n + \sum_{k\ne n} \frac{n!}{k!}n^k > n^n$$

Answer (score 12):

Hint: Show that
$$
\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k >\int_1^n\ln x\, dx.
$$

Comment: That's a clever approach! Nice one!

Answer (score 6):

Inductively, if $n!>\frac{n^n}{e^n}$ and you multiply both sides by $n+1$, then you have that $(n+1)!>(n+1)\frac{n^n}{e^n}$, so it suffices to prove that $(n+1)\frac{n^n}{e^n}>\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n+1}}$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: +1 This requires the least amount of machinery of the presented solutions, I think.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: write out the series for $e^n$ and pick out a relevant term amongst the positive terms which make up the sum.

Comment: You posted a hint and Deven independently posted a solution using the same idea => 10 vote difference. Isn't that always so? +1 to both of you from me has been there from the beginning, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I had originally written this up for another question but it seems fitting here as well. Maybe this can help someone.

Depending on how you introduced $e$, you might be able to use the fact that there are two sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with

$$\begin{align}
a_n ~~~&:=~~~ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right ) ^n \\ ~ \\
b_n ~~~&:=~~~ \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) ^{-n}
\end{align}$$

and

$$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} a_n ~~~=~~~ \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} b_n ~~~=~~~ e \\ ~ \\$$

While both sequences converge to the same limit, $a_n$ approaches from the bottom and $b_n$ approaches from the top:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

pts = np.arange(0, 20, 1)
a_n = lambda n: (1+1/n)**n
b_n = lambda n: (1-1/n)**(-n)

plt.errorbar(x = pts, xerr = None, y = a_n(pts), yerr = None, fmt = "bx", markersize = "5", markeredgewidth = "2", label = "$a_n$")
plt.errorbar(x = pts, xerr = None, y = b_n(pts), yerr = None, fmt = "rx", markersize = "5", markeredgewidth = "2", label = "$b_n$")
plt.plot(pts, [np.exp(1)]*len(pts), color = "black", linewidth = 2, label = "$e$")
plt.xlim(1.5, 14.5)
plt.ylim(2.0, 3.5)
plt.legend(loc = "best")
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize = "22")
plt.show()
```

[image]

So we're going to use the following inequality:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} ~ : ~~~~~ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right ) ^n ~~~~<~~~~ e ~~~~<~~~~ \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) ^{-n} \tag*{$\circledast$} \\ ~ \\$$

---

**Thesis**

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, ~ n \geq 2 ~ : ~~~~~ e \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n ~~~~<~~~~ n! ~~~~<~~~~ n \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \\ ~ \\$$

---

**Proof By Induction**

**Base Case**

We begin with $n = 2$ and get

$$\begin{align}
& ~ && e \cdot \left ( \frac{2}{e} \right )^2 ~~~~&&<~~~~ 2! ~~~~&&<~~~~ 2 \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{2}{e} \right )^2 \\ ~ \\
& \Leftrightarrow && e \cdot \frac{4}{e^2} ~~~~&&<~~~~ 1 \cdot 2 ~~~~&&<~~~~ 2 \cdot e \cdot \frac{4}{e^2} \\ ~ \\
& \Leftrightarrow && \frac{4}{e} ~~~~&&<~~~~ 2 ~~~~&&<~~~~ \frac{8}{e} \\ ~ \\
&\Leftrightarrow && 2 ~~~~&&<~~~~ e ~~~~&&<~~~~ 4 ~~~~ \\
\end{align}
$$

Which is a true statement.

**Inductive Hypothesis**

Therefore the statement holds for some $n$. $\tag*{$\text{I.H.}$}$

**Inductive Step**

$$\begin{align}
& ~ && e \cdot \left ( \frac{n+1}{e} \right )^{n+1} \\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot \frac{1}{e} \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n+1}{e} \right )^n\\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \cdot \left ( \frac{n+1}{n} \right )^n\\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \cdot \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n\\ ~ \\
& \overset{\circledast}{<} && (n+1) \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \cdot e\\ ~ \\
& \overset{\text{I.H.}}{<} && (n+1) \cdot n!\\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1)!\\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot n!\\ ~ \\
& \overset{\text{I.H.}}{<} && (n+1) \cdot n \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n\\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^{n+1} \cdot e \\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n+1}{e} \right )^{n+1} \cdot \left ( \frac{n}{n+1} \right )^{n+1} \cdot e \\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n+1}{e} \right )^{n+1} \cdot \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right )^{n+1} \cdot e \\ ~ \\
& \overset{\circledast}{<} && (n+1) \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n+1}{e} \right )^{n+1} \cdot \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right )^{n+1} \cdot \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right )^{-(n+1)} \\ ~ \\
& = && (n+1) \cdot e \cdot \left ( \frac{n+1}{e} \right )^{n+1} \\ ~ \\
\end{align}
$$

**Conclusion**

Therefore the statement holds $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, ~ n \geq 2$.
$$\tag*{$\square$}$$