# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^nn!}{n^n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the following series convergent?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^nn!}{n^n}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

$$n! >(\frac{n}{e})^n$$

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475927/how-to-prove-n-fracnen?lq=1).