# The limit superior of R given as lim sup of $\frac{1}{\left| \left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \right|}$ as n approaches infinity

Tags: limits

What is the limit superior of  $\dfrac{1}{\left| \left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \right|}$ as n approaches infinity?

So far I have been able to establish that $n≤n!$ for $n≥1$ which the gives that $\frac1{n!}≤\frac1n$ from there I used the sandwich theorem on $0≤\frac1{n!}≤\frac1n$ to reach the conclusion that $\frac1{n!}$ tends towards zero as $n$ approaches infinity. I am now stuck on how to deal with the exponent $\frac1n$.

Comment: This  expression simplifies to $(n!)^{1/n}.$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So far I have been able to establish that $n \leq n!$ for $n \geq 1$ which the gives that $\frac{1}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{n}$  from there I used the sandwich theorem  on $0 \leq \frac{1}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ to reach the conclusion that $\frac{1}{n!}$ tends towards zero as n aprochies infinity. I am now stuck on how to deal with the exponent $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: See also: [How to show $(1/n!)^{1/n}$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338954) or [$\lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136626).

Answer (score 0):

If $n\ge 3$ there are more than $n/2$ integers from $1$ to $n$ that are greater than $n/3.$

So $n\ge 3 \implies n!>(n/3)^{n/2}\implies n!^{1/n}>((n/3)^{n/2})^{1/n}=\sqrt {n/3}\,.$