# Asymptotic growth of factorial and exponential

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function, factorial

I know that $n!$ growth faster than $a^n$, ([Do factorials really grow faster than exponential functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351815/do-factorials-really-grow-faster-than-exponential-functions)).

But what about this: $n!$ and $2^{2^n}$ ($2$ to the power of $2$ to the power of $n$)? Can you please prove?

Comment: $2^{2^n}$ grows faster than $n!$ but I reply "What about $2^{2^n}$  vs $(n!)!$?" maybe $2^{2^{2^n}}$. For $n=4$ we have already $19,729$ digits...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose $n$ times of $2^n$:
$$2^n\times\cdots\times2^n = 2^{n^2}$$

It's straightforward to show that $n < 2^n$  and growth of $n$ is less than $2^n$. Therefore, growth of $n!$ is less than  $2^{n^2}$.  Also $n^2 < 2^n$ and for their growth respectively. Hence, growth of $n!$ is less than $2^{2^n}$.

Comment: Since when does $(2^n)^n\neq 2^{n^2}$