# Running time that is neither polynomial nor exponential

Tags: optimization, asymptotics

I have to find an example of a running time that is neither polynomial nor exponential. At first I was thinking about $n!$ but I think that this is bounded below by exponential functions for large n (which would imply exponential running time). Could someone help me out with this question? Thanks in advance

Comment: $n!$ is not bounded above by an exponential though - it grows faster than any exponential. So it seems like a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial intuition is correct, factorial time is certainly not polynomial, and it is **not** bounded above by exponential time (if by exponential time you mean $a^n$ for some $a$). Note, however, that there is another category called the *superexponential* time, of the form $n^n$, which does indeed outgrow $n!$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351815/do-factorials-really-grow-faster-than-exponential-functions) for more details.