# Find whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n+1)!}{4^n+\frac{1}{π^n}}$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

In this exercise I have to find whether this series is convergent or divergent, and I do not really know what to do with denominator, that is why I would be grateful for any tips or solutions.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2n+1)!}{4^n+\frac{1}{π^n}}$$

Comment: Interesting. I believe that from this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351815/do-factorials-really-grow-faster-than-exponential-functions, the numerator would grow faster than the denominator and the function would eventually diverge.

Comment: Pretend that the denominator is $4^n$.

Comment: Does the $n$th term go to $0$?

Answer (score 3):

Big hint: Consider the general term:

- its numerator is clearly $> \ n!$
- its denominator is less than $ \ < 5^n$. (you will have to provide a rigorous proof)

Therefore the general term is $>\dfrac{n!}{5^n}$ which tends to $\infty$...

As a consequence, the given series is divergent.