# Calculating the limit $\lim((n!)^{1/n})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factorial, radicals

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((n!)^{1/n})$. The question seemed rather simple at first, and then I realized I was not sure how to properly deal with this at all. My attempt: take the logarithm, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln((n!)^{1/n}) =  \lim_{n\to\infty} (1/n)\ln(n!) =  \lim_{n\to\infty} (\ln(n!)/n)$$
Applying L'hopital's rule: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} [n! (-\gamma + \sum(1/k))]/n! = \lim_{n\to\infty} (-\gamma + \sum(1/k))=  \lim_{n\to\infty} (-(\lim(\sum(1/k) - \ln(n)) + \sum(1/k))
 = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\ln(n) + \sum(1/k)-\sum(1/k)
 = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\ln(n))$$
I proceeded to expand the $\ln(n)$ out into Maclaurin form
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (n + (n^2/2)+...) = \infty$$
Since I $\ln$'ed in the beginning, I proceeded to e the infinity
 $$= e^\infty
 = \infty$$

So am I write in how I approached this or am I just not on the right track? I know it diverges, I was just wanted to try my best to explicitly show it.

Comment: Better use Stirling.

Comment: You could use the fact that for a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive terms, if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ exists, then so does $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\root n\of{a_n}$ and the two limits are equal. Apply this to $a_n=n!$

Comment: This is utterly illegible. Please use latex mode to write formulas, or at the very least fix those linebreaks...

Comment: See also  [$\lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/136626) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/136626).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Why is this not a duplicate? 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I have mentioned your suggestion [in CRUDE chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2019/12/23), perhaps somebody responds there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty} (n!)^{1/n} &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(\tfrac{1}{n} \ln n!)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \exp[\tfrac{1}{n} (\ln 1+\ln 2+\cdots + \ln n)]\\
&\ge \lim_{n\to\infty}\exp \left[ \frac{1}{n} \int_1 ^n \ln x dx\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp \frac{n\ln n -n+1}{n} 
\end{aligned}
$$

and last side of above inequality diverges.

Comment: How the sum of logarithms becomes greater than the integration?

Comment: @BijanDatta Replace the sum to the integration by using a step function and compare the step function with $\ln x$.

Answer (score 75):

By rearranging terms, we can see that
$$(n!)^2=[1\cdot n][2\cdot (n-1)][3\cdot (n-2)] \cdots [(n-1)\cdot 2][n\cdot 1].$$
Each of the $n$  products $(k+1)\cdot (n-k)$, for $0\le k<n$, is $\ge n$. Thus 
$$(n!)^2 \ge n^{n} \quad\text{and therefore}\quad (n!)^{1/n}\ge \sqrt{n}.$$

Comment: this is by far the simplest answer +1

Comment: @AndréNicolas With $n/2$ no justification is required as one of the factors will be at least $n/2$. It's actually true that $0\le k<n$ implies $(k+1)(n-k)>n$, but why not using an obvious inequality instead?

Comment: Because the original inequality is stronger (though far short of the truth) and prettier.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you please show me how to prove $\ (k+1)\cdot (n-k)\ge n$?

Comment: @ManjoyDas If $k=0$, it's obvious. Now for $1\leq k\leq\frac n2$, you have $(k+1)\cdot (n-k)\geq (k+1)\frac n2\geq n.$ Similarly, complete the other case.

Answer (score 12):

Taking $\log$ and using Stolz-Cesaro:
$$
\log\lim_{n\to\infty}n!^{1/n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n!^{1/n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\log 1+\cdots+\log n\over n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\log(n+1)\over(n+1)-n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n+1)=\infty,$$
so $\lim n!^{1/n}=\infty$.

Comment: @Milan, Stolz-Cesaro works in the case of $\lim = \infty$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166597/reverse-stolz-cesaro-theorem, https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf.

Comment: Sorry, i was the one who should have checked the statement of the theorem

Answer (score 9):

Assume WLOG that $n$ is even.

Clearly, 
$$n!=1\cdot2\cdots n > \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)\cdots n>  \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: how does the 1st inequality hold?

Comment: all of the factors exist in the LHS product plus more

Comment: oh yess. I missed that n is even

Comment: The theorem is correct for all $n$ of course, but writing it would just involve some floors or ceils - not sure...

Comment: I think $1\cdot2\cdots n < \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)\cdots \left(\frac{n}{2}+n\right)$ would be right

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, using Stirling approximation $$n!\simeq\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-n} n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$ helps a lot. Raising to power $\frac{1}{n}$ then leads to $$(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}\simeq\ (2 \pi n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{n}{e}$$ For large values of $n$, the first term goes to $1$ and so $(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ behaves as $\frac{n}{e}$

A better approximation can be obtained using Taylor series; writing the beginning of the expansion as $$(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}\simeq\frac{n}{e}+\frac{\log (2 \pi  n)}{2 e}$$ which shows how would behave $$\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$ for large values of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

The inequalities
I often find useful
because of their simplicity
are
$(n/e)^n
< n!
< (n/e)^{n+1}
$.
These give
$\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}
\to 1/e
$.

These follow from
$(1+1/n)^n
< e
< (1+1/n)^{n+1}
$
(which have been
proven here
many times).

Answer (score 0):

Let a $n\in \Bbb N$. By definition $$[\frac n2]\leq \frac n2<[\frac n2]+1.$$
Then $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot[\frac n2]\cdot ([\frac n2]+1)\cdot...\cdot n>(\frac n2)^{n-[\frac n2]+a}>(\frac n2)^{\frac n2 +a}$, so $(n!)^{\frac 1n}>(\frac n2)^{\frac 12 + \frac an}\to \infty$, thus $(n!)^{\frac 1n}\to \infty.$ We set $a:=0$, if $n$ is even, and $a:=1$, if it is odd.