# Convergence of single variable power series

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know whether the following power series converges or diverges.

$$1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots.$$

My intutition tells me that for any nonzero $x$, the series diverges, but I am not sure how to verify it

How should I verify it?

Comment: Try showing it converges using the [Ratio Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), instead.

Comment: Well. This is simply $e^{-x}$, and yes it does converge for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: You shouldn't try to verify it because it's unverifiable.

Answer (score 1):

The series does converge for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and it is the series expression for $e^{-x}$. First of all, notice that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n!)^{1/n}=\infty$ (a proof of this fact can be [found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706461/limn1-n-trouble-with-calculating-this-limit)). So the [radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of the above power series is 
\begin{eqnarray}
R=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n!)^{1/n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} (n!)^{1/n}=\infty.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore the series converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now compare the series with the talyor series expression for $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n+1\gt x$ you have $\frac {x^n}{n!}\gt \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Ignoring the finite number of initial terms, and with a little more work, you can use the alternating series test to show that this converges (you have to show the magnitude of the terms goes to zero).