# Does $n!^{\frac{1}{n}}$ Converge?

Tags: real-analysis

I am hoplessly trying the ratio test. So if $a_n=n!^{\frac{1}{n}}$ then we compute the limit of the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ if it turns out to be less than 1 it converges. So
$$\frac{(n+1)!^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n!^{\frac{1}{n}}}=(n!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}}(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$.

Now I know that $(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ converges to 1. How do I proceed?

Comment: Apply Stirling's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Stirling%27s_approximation) and you're good to go, the usual ratio test won't lead you anywhere (as far as I remember)

Comment: @ b00n heT So by Stirling approximation $n!$ is asymptotically similar to $\sqrt{2 \pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$. So I can conclude that $n!^{\frac{1}{n}}$ has the same asymptotic behavior as  $\Big{(}\sqrt{2 \pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n\Big{)}^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Of course the latter goes to infinity. Therefore so does $n!^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Is that fine?

Comment: I don't think it converges. Use the term test, i.e., show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n!^{1/n}=\infty$

Comment: Yes @AloysiusGodinho.

Comment: Cool @ b00n heT. Thanks for the hint. But I am inquisitive Is there a  standard technique that I can apply to functions like these.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706461/calculating-the-limit-limn1-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

You can either use Stirling approximation as suggested. An alternate way if you're not supposed to know Stirling approximation is to go through logarithm:

$$\ln a_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k$$ and then using that logarithm is increasing to compare the sum to an integral.

Comment: Thanks I guess taking logarithm in situations involving products like this is the best way to gauge the growth of the sequence.

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking me to compare the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n Log(k)$ with the integral of the same function from $1 \rightarrow k$ right? since they both converge or diverge together.

Comment: Yes that is right. For $n \ge 1$ integer you have $\ln x \ge \ln n$ for $x \in [n,n+1]$.

Answer (score 6):

(I added a more general result at the end.)

Here is a completely elementary proof
that does not need
Stirling's formula
or even logs:

$n!
=\prod_{k=1}^n k
>\prod_{k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}^n k
>\lfloor n/2 \rfloor^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}
\ge\lfloor n/2 \rfloor^{ n/2}
$.

Therefore,
$n!^{1/n}
>\lfloor n/2 \rfloor^{1/2}
$
which diverges.

Note:
You can be more precise
and get better estimates,
but this is enough
to show divergence.

---

More generally,
if you take the terms
after $an$,
where $0 < a < 1$,
there are $n(1-a)$ terms,
each at least $an$,
so
$n!
>(an)^{n(1-a)}
$
or
$n!^{1/n}
>(an)^{1-a}
$.

This does not get to
the true value of
$cn$
for some $c$,
but it gets close.

---

Another tack:

Divide $1$ to $n$
into $k$ parts.
Each part has
$n/k$ numbers
with the smallest
of the $j^{th}$ part being
$nj/k$, 
for $j$ from $0$ to $k-1$.

Therefore,
skipping the first part,
$n!
>\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (nj/k)^{n/k}
=(n/k)^{n(k-1)/k}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} j^{n/k}
=(n/k)^{n(k-1)/k}(k-1)!^{n/k}
$
so
$n!^{1/n}
>(n/k)^{(k-1)/k}(k-1)!^{1/k}
$.

For example,
if $k=3$, then
$n!^{1/n}
>2^{1/3}(n/3)^{2/3}
$.

If we take
$k = \sqrt{n}$,
this shows that
$n!^{1/n}
>(\sqrt{n})^{1-1/\sqrt{n}}(\sqrt{n}-1)!^{1/\sqrt{n}}
$,
or
$n!
>(\sqrt{n})^{\sqrt{n}-1}(\sqrt{n}-1)!^{\sqrt{n}}
$.

Don't know if this is any use,
but it's fun.

Answer (score 2):

Let's follow what @b00n heT has suggested:

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left({n\over e}\right)^n$$

So we are left with finding the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2\pi n\right)^{1\over 2n}\left({n\over e}\right)$$

Let's look at the two terms of the product

$$\left(2\pi n\right)^{1\over 2n}\to 1$$
$${n\over e}\to \infty$$

So our sequence goes to $+\infty$