# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n})^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n})^{1/n}$

$$(n!)^2=[1\cdot n][2\cdot (n-1)][3\cdot (n-2)] \cdots [(n-1)\cdot 2][n\cdot 1].$$
Each of the $n$  products $(k+1)\cdot (n-k)$, for $0\le k<n$, is $\ge n$.

Thus
$$(n!)^2 \ge n^{n} \quad\implies \left(\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}\right)^{1/n}\ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}.$$

Please help to solve it

Comment: What do you mean by "find" the expression?

Comment: Did you just copy https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319992 ?

Comment: For large n use Stirling's formula for n!.

Comment: @MPW Sorry ... edited

Comment: @Gary Yes, Understand and taken help. I wanted to solve it in that style.

Comment: Take the logarithm. Stirling's formula is not so easy to obtain. But for $n\ge 2$ we have $(n\ln n)-n+1= \int_1^n\ln t dt<\ln (n!)<\int_2^{n+1}\ln t dt=(n+1)\ln (n+1)-(n+1)-(2-\ln 2),$ which is adequate for your Q.