# prove ${a_n} = \root n \of {n!} $ is monotonically increasing to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

> Prove ${a_n} = \root n \of {n!} $ is monotonically increasing to $\infty$

I already showed that $a_n$ diverges to infinity like this:
I used to the lemma which says that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L$ then $\root n \of {a_n} = L$

Questions:

1. How to show that $a_n$ is **strictly** monotone?
2. The lemma above is very useful, is there an alternative to show $a_n$ diverges?

**Update:**
I was wrong, the lemma doesn't fit here at all.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136626/lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-is-infinite) for 2..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we can show that $(n!)^{n+1}\lt ((n+1)!)^n$, we will be finished.

Equivalently,we want to show that $n!\lt (n+1)^n$. This is clear.

Comment: I thought about taking exponent from both sides, but that's getting a bit complicated from there.

Comment: The equivalence of the first and second forms are clear, the two sides of the first have a common factor $(n!)^n$. Then we take each term of the first to the power $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. (I wanted to give an argument that uses only arithmetic.)

Comment: Thank you, I also like the fact that it's pure arithmetic proof.

Comment: You are welcome. For proving divergence, which as been done many times on MSE, I like pairing, as in $(n!)(n!)=(1\cdot n)(2\cdot (n-1))\cdots (n\cdot 1)\ge n^n$. Now take the $\frac{1}{2n}$-th root.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Using GM-AM inequality. one have that
$$
(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(\prod_i i)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \frac{\sum_i i}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2}.
$$

Proof: Then you will have
$$
(n!)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}=(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}(n!)\le \frac{n+1}{2}(n!) = \frac{1}{2}((n+1)!)\le(n+1)!,
$$
and consequently
$$
(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le ((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}},
$$