# Logic behind the multiplicative form of "Gauss trick"?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was going through [$ \lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136626/lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-is-infinite)

I don't follow why/how this is true $(n!)^2 = (1 \cdot n) (2 \cdot (n-1)) (3 \cdot (n-2)) \cdots ((n-2) \cdot 3) ((n-1) \cdot 2) (n \cdot 1)\ge n^n$

I read that At least half the terms in the product for n! will be at least n/2 .. so ?

Please advise.

Comment: In each paired product other than the first and last, one of the terms is $\geq n/2$, and the other is $\geq 2$, so the product is $\geq n$.  The first and last terms are $n$, so they are also $\geq n$.

Comment: Thanks.. I have a thick brain.. but the aha moments are worth it :)

Comment: No, each of the $n$ factors is $\ge n$, so the product is $\ge n^n$. Take as an example $n=6,\;$ then you have 
$$(1\times 6)\times(2\times 5)\times(3\times 4)\times(4\times 3)\times(5\times 2)\times(6\times 1)$$
and each (factor) is $\ge 6$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(n!)^2 = \overbrace{(1 \cdot n)}^{\ge n} \overbrace{(2 \cdot (n-1))}^{\ge 2\cdot n/2} \overbrace{(3 \cdot (n-2))}^{\ge 2\cdot n/2} \cdots \overbrace{((n-2) \cdot 3)}^{\ge 2\cdot n/2} \overbrace{((n-1) \cdot 2)}^{\ge 2\cdot n/2} \overbrace{(n \cdot 1)}^{\ge n}\ge n^n$$

Answer (score 1):

If $k \le \frac{n-1}2$, then $4k^2 \le n^2 - 2n + 1$, and so

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n + 1}2 + k\right)\left(\frac{n + 1}2 - k\right)
& = \left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^2 - k^2 \\
& = \frac{n^2 + 2n + 1 - 4k^2}{4} \\
& \ge \frac{n^2 + 2n + 1 - (n^2 - 2n + 1)}{4} \\
& = n.
\end{align}