# What is the limit as k approaches infinity of $(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, radicals

What is the value of
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}?$$

One of my students concluded the limit was infinity – which I tend to agree with, but was unable to show that was the limit.  We knew  $k!$ was tough to beat, but $k^k$ does – so this situation was unclear.

Comment: Hint: notice that $k!$ is eventually bigger than $3^k$... Also $4^k$, and generally $a^k$...

Comment: This comment is better than the answers below.

Comment: the $k!\geq e(k/e)^k$

Comment: @LeonhardtvonM The $k! \ge (k/2)^{k/2}$ argument is allright.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I like better hints than proofs.

Comment: See also [Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319925/prove-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1-sqrtnn-0) and
[$\lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136626/lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-is-infinite)

Answer (score 13):

The limit is infinity. Just note that $k! \ge (k/2)^{k/2}$ (except for very small $k$).

Answer (score 6):

If we use stirling's approximation:
$$n!\sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$
we can conclude that the limit is infinity.

Answer (score 4):

We have $k! < k^k$. Further, we have
$$e^k = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{k^l}{l!} \implies e^k > \dfrac{k^k}{k!} \implies k! > \left(\dfrac{k}e\right)^k$$
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{k}e < (k!)^{1/k} < k$$
Now conclude.

Comment: That's a nice way to derive $k!\ge(k/e)^k$, never seen that one before. +1

Answer (score 0):

Just consider that $$(k!)^\frac{1}{k}=e^{ln(k!)^\frac{1}{k}}=e^\frac{ln(k!)}{k}$$

ie we have $$\lim_{k \to \infty} k!(^\frac{1}{k})= e^{\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{ln(k!)}{k}}$$

considering just the exponent and using L'Hospital rule you see $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1 \bullet 2 \bullet … \bullet k)}{k}=\frac{\ln(2)+\ln(3)+…+\ln(k)}{k}$$

Now bound the top by an integral of $\ln(k)$ i.e., $$ln(2)+ln(3)+…+ln(k) \ge \int_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln(x)dx = k \ln k-k   $$ from 2 to $\infty$ and evaluate i.e.,  , the k on the bottom will cancel. $\frac{k(\ln k-1)}{k}$=$\ln k-1$ which clearly $\rightarrow \infty$ as $k \to \infty$and you will have the limit to be $\infty$, thus your original limit is $$\lim_{k \to \infty}e^k=\infty$$

Comment: The math in this answer looks very dubious. And please don't write $e^\infty$, that's just asking for trouble. $\infty$ is not a number that can be used in algebraic expressions. I think the approach is workable, but the presentation is not very good.

Comment: Well, if it is dubious please point out why. And are you sure it is not valid to write that..?

Comment: Your bound just now goes the wrong way - you proved that the limit is *less* than infinity, which is not so useful.

Comment: $e^x$ is a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ if you prefer), and $\infty\notin\Bbb R$, so $e^\infty$ is an undefined expression. To prove that the limit is $\infty$, you need to show that it is larger than any $M$, and just note that if $x$ exceeds $\log M$ then $e^x$ exceeds $M$, so if you can show that $\log{n!}/n$ is eventually larger than any constant (in particular $\log M$) then you are done.

Comment: Okay, if any other members with experience tell me it is all incorrect than I will go ahead and delete it. Thanks

Comment: However I think the writing of e to the infinity is of less importance

Comment: It's not incorrect, in the sense that you have the right idea, but there are some mistakes in the proof. As for the integral, you should use a lower bound instead so that $\sum_{i=2}^k\log k\ge\int_1^k\log x\,dx=k\log k-k+1$.