# Calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty} [(1/n)(n!)^{1/n}] $

Tags: limits

I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n!)^{1/n} = \infty$ But I can't figure out the $\lim_{n\to\infty} [(1/n)(n!)^{1/n}]$ since it is infinity over zero. Please help.

Comment: See N. S.'s answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136626/lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-is-infinite).

Comment: You can also compute $\lim {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ with $a_n=n!/n^n$. This limit exists; whence  $\lim \root n\of{a_n}$ exists and is equal to  $\lim {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rewrite the function as 
$$
\lim_{ n \to \infty} e^{\frac{\log n!}{n} - \log n}
$$
Then use the integral approximation for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k$ to get the result $(e^{-1} )$.