# What is the limit of the sequence n!/4^n?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

I am trying to find the limit of the sequence by using root test and I don't understand why the limit is not zero?
(the answer is inf).

Comment: why do you think the answer should be zero? can you show us your attempt?

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n!}{4^n} = \dfrac14 \cdot \dfrac24 \cdot \dfrac34 \cdot \dfrac44 \cdot \dfrac54 \cdots = \infty$

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty$

Comment: See also [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77550).

Comment: why lim sup =inf ??

Comment: You should probably clarify whether you wanted to ask about about $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{4^n}$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{4^n}$. (The answer you accepted would suggest that you meant the latter.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} &=& \displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{n!}{4^n}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac14 \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n!} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac14 \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\exp\left(n \ln n - n\right)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac14 \limsup_{n\to\infty} \exp\left(\ln n - 1\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac1{4e} \limsup_{n\to\infty} n \\
&=& \infty
\end{array}$$

Hence the sequence diverges to infinity.

Comment: why n!=exp(n*ln n -n)??

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)

Comment: Perhaps it is worth adding a link to this question: [$\lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136626), where various approaches to the limit of $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ can be seen in the answers.

Answer (score 23):

A fancy and nice (imo) way to do it. Take

$$a_n:=\frac{4^n}{n!}\implies\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{4^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{4^n}=\frac4{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0<1\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$

$$\text{converges}\;\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\implies\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}=\infty$$

Comment: The first expression you wrote for $a_n$ is incorrect.

Comment: I like this approach more than any other.+1

Comment: @HocNgo I don't understand: what is wrong?

Comment: @DonAntonio, you swapped the numerator and denominator. The correct expression for $a_n$ should be $$ a_n = \frac{n!}{4^n}.$$Hmm, I just realized your $a_n$ is not the same as the one I thought in the original problem. My apology.

Comment: @HocNgo At the end, he considers $1/a_n$, which is your limit.

Answer (score 10):

One may note that

$$n!=1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times\dots\times n>24\times5^{n-4}$$

Thus,

$$a_n>\frac{24}{5^4}\times\left(\frac54\right)^n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 8):

All the answers given so far use valid techniques for showing that the sequence goes to infinity. But don't forget you can *always* go back to the definition of a limit. The limit of a sequence is infinite if you can choose any value, call it $K$, and find an index $k$ such that $a_n > K$ for all $n > k$.  So, we can pick a value -- one billion -- and find a $k$ such that every $a_n$ past that is greater than a billion.

Can you prove that? Hints: can you show that:

- once you are past the first few elements, the sequence is greater than one
- once you are past the first few elements, the sequence is monotone increasing
- that ${5 K}/{4} > K$
- that these three facts can be combined to show a proof of the desired property

Answer (score 6):

Let $\displaystyle{u_n=\frac{n!}{4^n}}$. We observe that :

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n+1}{4}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$$

Hence, for $n\ge N$, with $N$ large enough :

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\ge2$$

and thus :

$$\forall n\ge N,\,u_n\ge 2^{n-N}u_N$$

This proves that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=+\infty}$

Answer (score 5):

You can use Stirling's approximation for very large $n$ ,  $$n! \approx n^ne^{-n} \sqrt{2\pi n}$$

Your limit becomes : $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n!}{4^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big(\frac{n}{4e}\Big)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}=\infty $$

Since $n$ is very large, doesn't matter if you divide it by $4e$, it will also be very large than $1$.