# Convergence or divergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2^n\cdot n^5}{n!}$ using integral test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Finding convergence or Divergence of series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2^n\cdot n^5}{n!}$$ using integral test.

What i try::

$$\frac{2}{1}+\frac{4\cdot 32}{2!}+\frac{8\cdot 3^5}{3!}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=4}\frac{2^n\cdot n^5}{n!}$$

Using $$\frac{n!}{2^n}=\frac{4!}{2^4}\frac{5}{2}\frac{6}{2}\cdots \cdots >1\Longrightarrow \frac{n!}{2^n}>1$$

So $$\frac{2^n}{n!}\leq 1\Longrightarrow \frac{2^n\cdot n^5}{n!}<n^5$$

How do i solve it Help me please, Thanks

Comment: There is no integral test in what you tried. Was this really assigned to you ?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2^n\cdot n^5}{n!} = \frac{6^n}{n!} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n<\frac{6^n}{n!} $$

Comment: Thanks zkutch.But i did not understand How can i use integral test. Thanks

Comment: Happy to be helpful. But are you sure about exactly integral test?

Comment: @jacky: See my answer for one way using the integral test.

Answer (score 3):

The integral test requires an upper bound which is not immediate. Instead we can relate the series to the Taylor expansion of the exponential.

$$n^5=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)+10(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)\\+65(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)+285(n-3)(n-4)+781(n-4)+1024$$ so that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^nn^5}{n!}=
\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\left(\frac1{(n-5)!}+\frac{10}{(n-4)!}+\frac{65}{(n-3)!}+\frac{285}{(n-2)!}+\frac{781}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1024}{n!}\right)$$ (the terms with a factorial of a negative must be omitted).

This sum is obviously convergent and equals $ae^2+b$ where $a,b$ are rational numbers.

[You can show convergence in an easier way (see @zkutch); but my goal was to show that one can find the exact value.]

Comment: Your first sentence is not right; see my answer.

Comment: @user21820: you are right, I will rephrase.

Comment: Thanks for your edit! It's great now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know "you have to use integral test " or ...? but I suggest ratio test
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=
\\\dfrac{\dfrac{2^{n+1}\cdot (n+1)^5}{(n+1)!}}{\dfrac{2^n\cdot n^5}{n!}}\\=\frac{2(n+1)^5}{(n+1)n^5}\\=\frac{2(n+1)^4}{n^5}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

All solutions given are very good and effective, as a further alternative by root test we obtain

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n\cdot n^5}{n!}}=\frac{2\cdot \sqrt[n]{n^5}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\to 0$$

indeed by [**standard limits**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136626/505767)

- $\sqrt[n]{n^5}\to 1$
- $\sqrt[n]{n!}\to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the integral test, you need to find an integrable upper bound like say:
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

$\dfrac{2^n·n^5}{n!} ≤ \dfrac{2^n·n^5}{1·2^{n-8}·(n/2)^7}$ for every natural $n ≥ 4$.

Can you finish now?