# Is the sequence $(n!e^{n}/n^{n})$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that $n!/n^{n} = o(1)$ as $n \to \infty,$ but what can I say about $e^{n}$ involved here?

Comment: Hint: Stirling's approximation.

Comment: The relevant result is Stirling's formula, which is usually proven by comparing $\ln(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln(k)$ to $\int_1^n \ln(x) dx$. It turns out that this diverges, but "critically", in the sense that if you replace $e$ by any larger number, you don't get divergence.

Comment: Ah, Stirling's, yes; thanks.

Comment: Refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196710/calculation-of-limit-without-stirling-approximation/1205727#1205727

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$
we see that the given sequence is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

From the telescopic product:
$$ n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$ n! = \frac{n^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}\tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ \log\left(\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)\geq (1-\log 2)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\geq\frac{3}{10}\log n \tag{3}$$
implies that $\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}$ diverges as $n\to +\infty$.