# How to find the limit of $ \dfrac{n! e^n}{n^n} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we find limit of the sequence $\dfrac{n!e^n}{n^n} $? I know its limit is infinity. First, I showed it is strictly increasing(by taking ratio of terms) and then showed it is not Cauchy sequence. I want to prove this by some other method, like comparing with other sequence. Can any one give some hint?

Comment: By Stiriling's Formula the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: How could you show that it is not Cauchy ?

Comment: Also: [Elementary proof for $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n} = +\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494776) and [Limit $c^n n!/n^n$ as $n$ goes to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1904113) and  [Is the sequence $(n!e^{n}/n^{n})$ convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1207462) – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdfrac%7Bn!e%5En%7D%7Bn%5En%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3):

One quick solution is using Stirling's approximation, which states

$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n}$

Then $\frac{n! e^n}{n^n} \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}$ which approaches $\infty$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me write little more exact estimation, from which, by the way, comes Stirling.
$$\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n<n!$$