# Is the sequence $\frac{e^nn!}{n^n}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Is the sequence $\frac{e^nn!}{n^n}$ convergent?

All I tried is to calculate - $$\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$$ but it isn't helping...

Comment: Do you know the Stirling approximation to the factorial?

Comment: @thedude no. I will check.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196710/calculation-of-limit-without-stirling-approximation) also.

Comment: @thedude cool!!!

Comment: By very elementary means we can show there exists $ K>0$ such that $(\frac {n}{e})^n K\sqrt n\; \cdot  (n!)^{-1} \to 1$ as $n\to \infty.$ Stirling's Formula is that $K=\sqrt {2\pi}\;$, which is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). It should be clear from here.