# Pointwise and uniform convergence : How to calculate the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to check the pointwise and uniform convergence of the below power series.

- $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}x^n}$

We have that \begin{equation*}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\end{equation*}

How do we calculate that limit?

Comment: Ratio test may be easier for you in this case.

Comment: One way is to appeal to Stirling's Formula.  The interesting case is $x=-e$ though Stilring's Formula works here too.

Comment: Related [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2734257/505767).

Answer (score 1):

From the more general result presented here

- [Inequality involving $\limsup$ and $\liminf$: $ \liminf(a_{n+1}/a_n) \le \liminf((a_n)^{(1/n)}) \le \limsup((a_n)^{(1/n)}) \le \limsup(a_{n+1}/a_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69386/505767)

we have that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to L \implies \sqrt[n]{a_n} \to L$$

For the application see the related

- [Why does $\;\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{n}{n!^{1/n}}=e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2734257/505767)

Comment: Ok, so we get that the pointwise converegnce is on $(-e,e)$. To check now the boundaries... How can we calculate the limit of $\frac{n!}{n^n}e^n$ ? I have done the following: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}e^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{e^n}{n^n}\cdot n!=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left (\frac{e}{n}\right )^n\cdot n!$$ does this help us? How can we continue? Do we maybe apply the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Refer to this [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1196710/505767) for that.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You are very welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the ration test to check the convergence. One has
$$\frac{\left( \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\right)}{\left( \frac{n!}{n^n}\right)} = \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$$

which tends to $e^{-1}$. So the radius of convergence is $e$. So the series converges for all $|x|<e$, and diverges for all $|x|>e$.

Now let's study what happened for $x=-e$ and $x=e$. One has, by Stirling formula,
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}e^n \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}$$

So $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}e^n = +\infty$$

so both series
$$\sum  \frac{n!}{n^n}e^n \quad \text{ and } \quad \sum  \frac{n!}{n^n}(-e)^n$$

diverge.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)